# Story where everyone had to get a daily injection of mind control drug

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

At first I thought the story I was trying to remember was *1984*, or *Brave New World*. But I have been going through them both and they are not it.
I hope this is a real story and not my memory playing mash-up.

What I remember is that everyone of that time had to get a daily injection of mind control drug. The main character came across a secret rebel group. In the meeting room, the main character got his first experience with tobacco cigs. He met a person who had two different color eyes.
Sometime after the meeting, he made a foil packet with cotton inside it for the arm injections. This way he could fake the injections, and eventually weaned off the drug. Without the drug he could think much differently.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver? The main character has unusual eyes (pale rather than bi-coloured)

Comment: @Valorum I don't recall mandatory _injections_?

Comment: @DavidW - There's a fairly extensive scene where a kid gets an injection. Into his face, if memory serves. In the movie I think they made it explicitly injections that they get each day

Comment: Daily *hidden* injection of a drug that makes people dumb or obedient is a pretty common trope. Sometimes the drug is swallowed instead of injected. But in most books or comics or movies this is a secret, ie, the people don't know that they are taking this drug.

Comment: @Valorum - IIRC in *The Giver* they take pills.  In the book.  Didn't know (or care :-) ) that there is also a movie....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[This Perfect Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Perfect_Day) by Ira Levin.

I remembered the foil covered pad to defeat the injections:

> He was the first one in the dining room; ate and drank, and went back to his room with a cake wrapper folded loosely in his pocket. He opened the wrapper, put it on the desk, and smoothed it down flat with his hand. He folded the square of foil neatly in half, and the half into thirds. He pressed the packet flat and held it; it was thin despite its six layers. Too thin? He put it down again.
>
> He went into the bathroom and, from the cabinet’s first-aid kit, got cotton and the cartridge of tape. He brought them back to the desk. He put a layer of cotton on the foil packet—a layer smaller than the packet itself—and began covering the cotton and the packet with long overlapping strips of skin-colored tape. He stuck the tape ends lightly to the desktop.
> ...
> He finished the taping and then peeled the tape ends from the desk and carried the bandage he had made into the bathroom. He laid it foil-side up on the edge of the sink and pushed up his sleeve. He took the bandage and put the foil carefully against the inner surface of his arm, where the infusion disc would touch him. He clasped the bandage and pressed its tape border tightly to his skin.
>
> A leaf. A shield. Would it work?

Comment: Also note that it is the main character, "Chip", who has two different-coloured eyes.  The secret rebel who brings Chip into the group is an albino.  Both are extremely unusual in a society that pushes uniformity in appearance and behaviour.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I think that is it! "This Perfect Day" 
Ok, I'm off to go read this again to be sure.
Thank you!!